# Java 8 POJO objects filter pojo based on common multiple key combination and sum on one field

Tags: java-8

I have a class Sales.

```
Class Sales {
String month; String year; String city; String state; String sales;
}
```

Have a list of Sales objects

```
"result" :[ 

{
"month" : "JAN",
"year":  "2000",
"state" : "State1",
"city" :  "City1",
"sales" : "10"
}, 
{
"month" : "JAN",
"year" :  "2000",
"state" : "State1",
"city" :  "City2",
"sales" : "20"
},
{
"month" : "JAN",
"year" :  "2000",
"state" : "State2",
"city" :  "City3",
"sales" : "30",
},
{
"month" : "JAN",
"year" :  "2000",
"state" : "State2",
"city" :  "City1",
"sales" : "40"
},
{
"month" : "FEB",
"year" :  "2000",
"state" : "State1",
"city" :  "City1",
"sales" : "5",
},
{
"month" : "FEB",
"year" :  "2000",
"state" : "State1",
"city" :  "City2",
"sales" : "15"
}
]
```

[image: It would be represented as below picture]

Now what I trying to achieve is the total of sales like depicted in above picture, how can i achieve the same using java 8. I tried grouping by JAVA 8 features, but no luck.

```
    list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getMonth(), Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getSales(),
                                            Collectors.summingInt(foo->foo.getTotalSales()))))
          .forEach((id,total)->System.out.println(id+"\t"+total));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the type representing the sales.

```
String sales;
```

should be

```
int sales;
```

or

```
long sales;
```

`String` should not be the type for things that are naturally represented by numeric types.

You could use `groupingBy()` but you should apply that on two distinct streams because you want to perform two kind of sales sums : a sales sum by state-city (row in your spreadsheet) and a sales sum by month (column in your spreadsheet).

```
Map<String, Integer> salesAmountByMonth = 
list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Sale::getMonth,
                        summingInt(Sale::getSales)));  

Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> salesAmountByStateByCity = 
list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Sale::getState,
                        groupingBy(Sale::getCity,
                                   summingInt(Sale::getSales))));
```

Comment: Thank you @davidxxx 
salesAmountByMonth works fine

There's little issue with salesAmountByCity it gives me 70 ...since city1 falls in both the state. I think i should group by both state and city..Trying that

Comment: @vidyashi You are welcome and you are also right about the nested grouping for the geographical criteria. You have several approaches to do that. I edited with one of them.

Comment: Thank you @davidxxx 
Can you please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600799/how-do-i-create-a-new-object-from-grouping-by-result