# How do I create a new object from grouping by result

Tags: java, java-8, grouping

For the example in [Java 8 POJO objects filter pojo based on common multiple key combination and sum on one field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579954/java-8-pojo-objects-filter-pojo-based-on-common-multiple-key-combination-and-sum)

After summing up, I need to create a new object of Sales type, having the totals ( sum result of group by ) Something like below

```
{
"month" : "Total",
"year":  "2000",
"state" : "State1",
"city" :  "City1",
"sales" : "15"
}
```

So i have created corresponding constructor in Sales and tried

```
list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Sale::getState,
                        groupingBy(Sale::getCity,
                                   summingInt(Sale::getSales).Collectors.mapping(e -> new Sales ("Total","2000","State1","City1",<summingInt result should come here>),
                                Collectors.toList()))));
```

How do I achieve something like above format in Java 8  ?

Comment: To be clear, you wanna group by state and city, and set the sales to be the sum of all sales in the group?

Comment: Yes correct @texasbruce
So that would be for State 1 for City1 Total is 15
using these value I want to create a separate objects of sales and similarly for other state and cities

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

instead of second `groupingBy` you can use `toMap` collector with merge function.

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Sales::getState,
        Collectors.toMap(Sales::getCity,Function.identity(),                              
              (s1, s2) -> new Sales(s1.month,...,s1.getSales() + s2.getSales()))));
```

Comment: OP wants to create new object. This code will overwrite the first object's Sales

Comment: @texasbruce, Thanks for saying that.

Answer (score 1):

Your direction is correct. The only thing needs to be done is the last step, which is combining all the sales number together into one object. You can't just use `summingInt` because it only returns an int and you don't have the other fields to construct an object. You can achieve this by using `reduce` to construct an initial object and adding the field value:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Sale::getState,
                        groupingBy(Sale::getCity,
                                   reducing( (a, b) -> new Sale(a.getMonth(), a.getYear(), a.getState(), a.getCity(), a.getSale() + b.getSale()) ))));
```

If you don't care about month and year, you can also create an identity object (initial object) and add only sales to it. It can reduce the number of temporary objects created:

```
list.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Sale::getState,
                        groupingBy(Sale::getCity,
                                   reducing(new Sale("Total", "2000", "", "", 0), (a, b) -> {
                                            a.setState(b.getState());
                                            a.setCity(b.getCity()); 
                                            a.setSales(a.getSales() + b.getSales()); 
                                            return a;
                                   } ))));
```

Make sure your year and months are the same across all objects, or it will be lost (unless you don't care in this case).